# What should the default value of this match statement be, also is there a way to unwrap a some case (chess in rust)

Tags: recursion, vector, rust, functional-programming, chess

I have a board which I am able to index with a `glam::IVec2`

```rust
struct Board{pieces: [char;64]}
type PieceOption = Option<char>;
```

this index method for board is

```rust
impl Index<IVec2> for Board {
    type Output = PieceOption;
    fn index(&self, v : IVec2) -> &Self::Output{
        if (v.abs() != v) || (v.max_element() > 8) {&None}
        else {
            let i : usize = (v.x + 8* v.y).try_into().unwrap();
            &Some(self.pieces[i])
        }
    }
}
```

Along with this PieceOption has methods `is_empty`, `is_ally` and `is_rival` so my question is as follows: what should the value of this recursive function be, in order to achieve type consistency I need the function to return a vector but I don't want to return the vector in the case where the next piece is of the same colour (is_ally). Along with this i was wondering if there is a way of unwrapping the `Some` values so that i do not need to type Some('char') for every single branch in the match statement, especially since i already filtered for the cases where the next move is out of bounds. this is the current function with the type inconsistency. This is the function currently implemented for the bishops only my intention is to feed this function consts for each of the movement types eg

```rust
const DIAGONALS : [IVec2; 4] = [
    ivec2(-1, -1), ivec2(-1, 1),
    ivec2(-1, 1), ivec2(1, 1)
];
```

so here is the current state of the function

```rust
impl Board {
    fn moves(&self, piece:&PieceOption, pos:IVec2, dir: Vec<IVec2>)->Vec<IVec2>{
        dir.into_iter()
            .map(|d| d+pos)
            .filter(|p| (p.abs() == *p) && p.max_element() < 8)
            .flat_map(|p|
                match piece{
                    Some('B')|Some('b')=>{
                        if self[p].is_empty() {self.moves(piece, p, vec![p-pos]).push(p)}
                        else if self[p].is_rival(*piece) {p}
                        else {()} /* here is where i do not wish to return a vector because
 this is likely a case where the next piece is an opponent*/
                        },
                    _ => () /* here is where i  do not wish to return a vector because 
the piece is likely empty space*/
                }
            )
            .collect()
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: I have realised `if let` is what I need to unwrap the option of the piece but I am really confused about what the return value of the if let statement should be, my current code for the function is

```rust
impl Board {
    fn moves(&self, piece:&PieceOption, pos:IVec2, dir: Vec<IVec2>)->Option<Vec<IVec2>>{
        dir.into_iter()
            .map(|d| d+pos)
            .filter(|p| (p.abs() == *p) && p.max_element() < 8)
            .flat_map(|p|
                if let Some(c) = piece{
                    match c{
                        'B'|'b'=>{
                            if self[p].is_empty() {self.moves(piece, p, vec![p-pos])?.push(p)}
                            else if self[p].is_rival(*piece) {Some(vec![p])}
                            else {None?}
                            },
                        _ => None
                        }
                } else {None}   
            )
            .collect()
    }
}
```

Along with this any advice on the format is greatly appreciated I'd like to know what people think about this potential solution and my apologies if the question is confusingly worded?

Full code can be found at:
https://github.com/LyndonAlcock/chess_test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of a closure passed to `flat_map` should be a collection.
If you don't want to add anything you can just return an empty one. `vec![]` in case of a `Vec`

Also `Option<char>` is copy so you can just pass in the thing instead of a reference.

```rust
impl Board {
    fn moves(&self, piece: PieceOption, pos: IVec2, dir: Vec<IVec2>) -> Vec<IVec2> {
        dir.into_iter()
            .map(|d| d+pos)
            .filter(|p| (p.abs() == *p) && p.max_element() < 8)
            .flat_map(|p|
                if let Some(c) = piece {
                    match c {
                        'B'|'b'=> {
                            if self[p].is_empty() {
                                let moves = self.moves(piece, p, vec![p-pos])
                                moves.push(p);
                                moves
                            } else if self[p].is_rival(*piece) {
                                vec![p]
                            } else {
                                vec![]
                            }
                        },
                        _ => vec![]
                        }
                } else {
                    vec![]
                }
            )
            .collect()
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, do you know anything about this error I'm getting,
```
cannot return reference to tempoary value returns referenc to data owned by the current function
```
this is for my index function, i guess i understand why I'm getting this but not sure how to solve the problem?

Comment: because i don't want piece options within the board since there should never be None Pieces as i will use ' ' to indicate empty